# Sidebar border not getting displayed

Tags: css

I am writing a website code but I am unable to display the border for the sidebar. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KU9Fs/) it is. And below is the code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<!--HTML WEBSITE
/*********************************************************************************************************************************************************NAME:FAHAD UDDIN*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>The New Boston</title>
<style type="text/css">
#container
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background:#BFBFBF;
}
#header
{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#333;

}
#header logo
{

}
#navigation
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px; 
}
#navigation ul
{
        background-color:#F00;
}
#navigation ul li
{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline;
    color:white;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-right:40px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
#sidebar
{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height:800px;
    border-bottom-color:#666;
    border:thin;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
#content
{
    float:left;
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    display:inline;

}
#footer
{
    clear:both;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#333;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><a/>Home</li>
                    <li><a href="#"><a/>Home</li>
                    <li><a href="#"><a/>Home</li>
                    <li><a href="#"><a/>Home</li>
                    <li><a href="#"><a/>Home</li>

                </ul>
            </div><!--Header Ends-->
        <div id="content">
        <p>This is the complain area. Fill complains here</p>
        </div><!--Content ENDS-->
        <div id="sidebar">
        <p>This is a website.</p>
        </div><!--SIDEBAR ENDS-->
        <div id="footer">
        </div><!--FOOTER ENDS-->
    </div><!--CONTAINER ENds-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your html has a bug- you've given a/ instead of /a:

```
<li><a href="#"><a/>Home</li>
```

2) float to the rescue: give this property in:

```
<p style="float: left">This is a website.</p>
```

and add float: right to #sidbar

3) What is border: thin in #sidebar? Give border: 1px solid. Read this for allowed attributes and their values: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

**UPDATE**

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/FPJTn/1/
The sidebar was breaking to the next line because of the value given for width for content. I have changed in #content css from width: 800px to width: auto.

Comment: Thanks. But its still not displaying properly. Its showing the sidebar below.

Comment: In JSFiddle, did you try moving the html output window fully to the left? If you did, you will see that sidebar does not go below. You have fixed the width of the sidebar to 300px- make it width: auto for it too